# R Shiny: dateRangeInput for month and year only

Tags: r, shiny, date-range

Is there a way to hack or create a `dateRangeInput()` selector in Shiny so that it selects only month and year (no day) or that it automatically selects the first day of the selected month without displaying a day choice? Or should I create another month-date picker (sliders, selectbox...)

```r
dateRangeInput('dateRange',
               label = "Pédiode d'analyse : ",
               format = "mm/yyyy", language = "fr",
               start = Sys.Date() %m-% months(12), 
               end = Sys.Date(),
               startview = "year",
               separator = " - ")
```

What I want is to delete this step when choosing the date :

[image]

Answer (score 15):

I've just used `airDatePicker()` to do this. You can edit the minimum view of the popup calendar to "month" and select the date format as "yyyy-mm".

```
airDatepickerInput("input_var_name",
                   label = "Start month",
                   value = "2015-10-01",
                   maxDate = "2016-08-01",
                   minDate = "2015-08-01",
                   view = "months", #editing what the popup calendar shows when it opens
                   minView = "months", #making it not possible to go down to a "days" view and pick the wrong date
                   dateFormat = "yyyy-mm"
                   )
```

The version I've just been working on looks like this (greyed may is where cursor was hovering when I took the screenshot):

[image: example date picker showing only month]

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at this custom function `monthStart` below which can be used to force the date to the first date of that month and year

**Example 1, Display the first day of a given month**. This may be useful if you want to use the date object for later use in your app, so it will always point to the first day of a given month and year

```
#rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)

monthStart <- function(x) {
  x <- as.POSIXlt(x)
  x$mday <- 1
  as.Date(x)
}

ui <- basicPage(dateRangeInput('dateRange',label = "Pédiode d'analyse : ",format = "mm/yyyy",language="fr",start = Sys.Date(), end=Sys.Date(),startview = "year",separator = " - "),
                textOutput("SliderText")
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  Dates <- reactiveValues()
  observe({
    Dates$SelectedDates <- c(as.character(monthStart(input$dateRange[1])),as.character(monthStart(input$dateRange[2])))
  })
  output$SliderText <- renderText({Dates$SelectedDates})
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

**Example 2, Display only the month and year**

```
#rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)

monthStart <- function(x) {
  x <- as.POSIXlt(x)
  x$mday <- 1
  as.Date(x)
}

ui <- basicPage(dateRangeInput('dateRange',label = "Pédiode d'analyse : ",format = "mm/yyyy",language="fr",start = Sys.Date(), end=Sys.Date(),startview = "year",separator = " - "),
                textOutput("SliderText")
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  Dates <- reactiveValues()
  observe({
    Dates$SelectedDates <- c(as.character(format(input$dateRange[1],format = "%m/%Y")),as.character(format(input$dateRange[2],format = "%m/%Y")))
  })
  output$SliderText <- renderText({Dates$SelectedDates})
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but I don't want that the user think that a day has been choosen, may be the best way to achieve that is to create a slider or a selectinput with mm-yyyy.

Comment: As I didn't know how you want to use this feature I included the day also, as in your analysis you might need it. For display purposes, you can simply render the date without the day. See updates above

Comment: Sorry i didn't explain it clearly, i've added a picture to show the step that i want to delete or hide.

Comment: in this case u should use a custom made text input